# Export selected rows from datagridview to excel using spire.XLS & C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, spire.xls

I'm trying to export the manually selected rows of a datagridview on a windows form application to a excel file using spire.XLS and add the sum of the last column in the last row. The datagridview data is like below:

[image: dgv]

And when I run the code after selecting the 1st & the last rows then the excel should look like:
[image: excel]

Here is my code:

```
        void ExportBtnXLSXClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Workbook book = new Workbook();
        Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
        sheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
        
        //Convert data from datagridview to datatable
        DataTable dt=GetDgvToTable(dataGridView1);

        //Export datatable to excel
        sheet.InsertDataTable(dt, true, 1, 1, -1, -1);
        //sheet.InsertDataTable(dt, true, 1, 1, true);
        sheet.Range[1,1,sheet.LastRow,sheet.LastColumn].AutoFitColumns();
        sheet.AllocatedRange.BorderAround(LineStyleType.Thin, borderColor:ExcelColors.Black);
        sheet.AllocatedRange.BorderInside(LineStyleType.Thin, borderColor:ExcelColors.Black);
        
        book.SaveToFile(@"C:\Users\Tamal\Desktop\Spire.XLS C#\Report.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
        book.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("Export complete");
    }
```

with the helper method

```
        public DataTable GetDgvToTable(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Column
        for (int count = 0; count < dgv.Columns.Count; count++)
        {
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[count].Name.ToString());
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        }

        //Row
        for (int count = 0; count < dgv.SelectedRows.Count; count++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int countsub = 0; countsub < dgv.Columns.Count; countsub++)
                //for (int countsub = 0; countsub < dgv.SelectedRows.Count; countsub++)
            {
                dr[countsub] = Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[count].Cells[countsub].Value);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        decimal total = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Cells[2].Value));
        dt.Rows.Add(total);
        return dt;
    }
```

But it is not showing the two rows that I selected and also the sum is showing on the 1st column of the last row in excel. How can I get the desired result?

Also, if I run the code multiple times then the data should not overwrite but just paste data after the last filled row, preferably keeping a row blank in between.

Here is how the datagridview looks like:
[image: dgv]

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple questions here. For starters, if you want to add multiple selections to the same workbook, then you will need to do some things differently…

1. check to see if the file already exists, if not, then create a new one, if it does exist then you will need to “open” it.
2. If the file already exists, then, after opening the file, you will need to check if the worksheet "Exported from gridview" exists… if it does exist, then, you will need to find the last used row and start adding the additional rows after that last row.
3. Finally save the file.

Currently, the code is simply “creating” a new workbook, then the code is overwriting the existing workbook if it already exists. So, if you want to “add” additional selections to the “same” workbook, you will need to add the code that checks if the file exists, and if so, find the next available row on the worksheet to add the additional items to as explained in the previous 3 steps above.

Below is a simple example that works however it was not tested well and I am confident you may need to adjust the code to fit your requirements.

First, in the `GetDgvToTable` method, it appears the code is grabbing the wrong rows when creating the table….

```
for (int count = 0; count < dgv.SelectedRows.Count; count++)
{
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  for (int countsub = 0; countsub < dgv.Columns.Count; countsub++)
    //for (int countsub = 0; countsub < dgv.SelectedRows.Count; countsub++)
    {
      dr[countsub] = Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[count].Cells[countsub].Value);
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Above, the code is looping through the “number of selected” rows. The problem is on the line…

```
dr[countsub] = Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[count].Cells[countsub].Value);
```

Specifically, at …

```
dgv.Rows[count].
```

Here the code is ignoring the “SELECTED” rows. In other words, if the “selected” rows were contiguous “selected” rows starting from the “first” row (0), then it will work. Unfortunately, the first “selected” row may not necessarily be the “first” row in the grid. The code is incorrectly making this assumption.

To fix this, I suggest you loop through the “selected” rows using a `foreach` loop through grids `SelectedRows` collection. This will ensure the code uses the “SELECTED” rows. The code change would look something like…

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows) {
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
    dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
  }
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Next, you state you want to additional selections to be added to the same worksheet with an empty row between the selections. This was previously discussed above. In the code below, it checks to see if the Excel file already exist and if it does, then opens that file. Next a check is made to see if the worksheet already exists. If it does not exist, then a new one is created.

Next a check is made to see if any “previous” selections have already been added to the worksheet. I am not that familiar with Spire, however, I noted that if you call the method…

```
sheet.LastRow…
```

It will return the next available row… EXCEPT if the worksheet is empty. When the worksheet is empty, this will return a value like 65,570. I will leave this to you to possibly figure out a more elegant way to get the next empty row. In this case I simply checked if the `sheet.LastRow` was over 60000. If the value is over 60000, then I assume the sheet is empty and simply set the next available row to 1. I am confident there is a better way to do this.

Given all this, the changes below to both methods appears to do as you want by adding the additional selection to the same worksheet “below” the previous selections.

```
public DataTable GetDgvToTable(DataGridView dgv) {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  //Column
  for (int count = 0; count < dgv.Columns.Count; count++) {
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(dgv.Columns[count].Name.ToString());
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  }
  //Row
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows) {
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
      dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }
  decimal total = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
      .Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Cells[2].Value));
  dt.Rows.Add("","Total",total);
  return dt;
}
```

Then the changes to the Export method.

```
private void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Workbook book = new Workbook();
  if (File.Exists(@"pathToFile\Report.xlsx")) {
    book.LoadFromFile(@"pathToFile\Report.xlsx");
  }
  Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets["Exported from gridview"];
  if (sheet == null) {
    sheet = book.CreateEmptySheet("Exported from gridview");
  }
  //Convert data from datagridview to datatable
  DataTable dt = GetDgvToTable(dataGridView1);
  //Export datatable to excel
  int startRow = sheet.LastRow + 2;
  if (startRow > 60000) {
    startRow = 1;
  }
  sheet.InsertDataTable(dt, true, startRow, 1, -1, -1);
  sheet.Range[1, 1, sheet.LastRow, sheet.LastColumn].AutoFitColumns();
  sheet.AllocatedRange.BorderAround(LineStyleType.Thin, borderColor: ExcelColors.Black);
  sheet.AllocatedRange.BorderInside(LineStyleType.Thin, borderColor: ExcelColors.Black);
  book.SaveToFile(@"pathToFile\Report.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
  book.Dispose();
  MessageBox.Show("Export complete");
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Thanks @JohnG, It is working however there was one more issue that I forgot to mention and that is the datagridview Header names are not showing in the excel file instead it is showing 'Column1', 'Column2' & 'Column3'...any idea how to fix that? Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I used the same code originally posted. The first `for` loop in the `GetDgvToTable` sets each columns name from the column name in the grid. I never changed any of that code. Also, your pictures show the proper headers. I can only assume the grid itself has column header names like “Column1”, Column2” etc.… I suggest you change the grids column names to what you want. How is the grid set up?

Comment: I've added a picture in my question as to how the `datagridview` looks and no the grid itself does not have column header names like “Column1”, Column2” etc

Comment: Ahh... I will assume the code that sets up the grid, is not setting the column `Name` property. This is what is used in the code... `dgv.Columns[count].Name.ToString()` ... It is probably setting the columns `HeaderText` property. Those are two different things. Therefore, either set the columns `Name` property in the code that sets up the grid or, change the above line to...  `dgv.Columns[count].HeaderText.ToString()`